# how can i get iPhoto pictures back after factory reset on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I have done a factory reset on my MacBook Pro because it was slow. Now i have lost my pictures on iPhoto. The pictures were not backed up on iCloud. 
How can i get iPhoto pictures back?

Comment: How did you do a factory reset?

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that you do not have a Time Machine backup, you cannot. If you can enter Time Machine, you may be able to restore your iPhoto library in `~/Pictures/iPhoto Library`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit too obvious, but if you have them on another device (such as an iPhone) you can import them again.